# Spring Data JPA won't handle Set<Enum> correctly

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying out Spring Boot (latest version, using Hibernate 4.3.7) and I have a problem with my `User` entity. Here it is (most important part of it):

```
@Entity
@Table("usr")
public class User {

    public static enum Role {
        UNVERIFIED, BLOCKED, ADMIN
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column
    @ElementCollection
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();

    (rest of properties, getters and setters etc)
}
```

I am also using `Spring Boot` JPA repositories to save my entities:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    User findByEmail(String email);

}
```

The problem is that when I add some `Roles` to `roles` set, Hibernate won't save it. It will create reference table, but it will only insert data to `User` table.

I tried to work this problem out, so I created pure `Java` + `Hibernate` project and copied my `User` class into it. Guess what? It worked!

Fun fact is that when I use pure `Hibernate` on my second project, created `roles` table looks different that the one created in my `Spring Boot` project.

On my clean `Hibernate` project I have table like:

```
User_roles:
   User_Id bigInt(20)
   roles int(11)
```

While using Spring JPA, I got

```
user_roles (notice lower case)
   User (no "_id" part)
   roles
```

What's going on? What I am doing wrong? Is it related to `Spring Boot` configuration? Thanks.

Comment: `@Column` seems wrong. Try removing it. Also try moving that enum to its own file. The naming strategy can be changed via setting `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate field naming issue with Spring Boot (naming strategy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36451620/hibernate-field-naming-issue-with-spring-boot-naming-strategy)

Answer (score 0):

The following should match your existing tables.

```
@Entity
@Table("usr")
public class User {

    public static enum Role {
        UNVERIFIED, BLOCKED, ADMIN
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ElementCollection 
    @CollectionTable(name = "User_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "User_Id")
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();

    (rest of properties, getters and setters etc)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but my problem is not matching existing tables, but different behavior or pure hibernate vs Spring Data JPA + saving related Enum set

Answer (score 0):

My Solution:

- Role.java

  public enum Role {

  USER, ADMIN

  }
- User.java

  @Entity

  @Table("usr")

  public class User {

  @Id

  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

  private long id;

  @ElementCollection(targetClass = Role.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)

  @JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"))

  @Column(name = "roles", nullable = false)

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)

  private Set roles;

  (rest of properties, getters and setters etc)

  }