# Hibernate field naming issue with Spring Boot (naming strategy)

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

Note that this code does work with plain Spring but not with Spring Boot(v1.3.3), is there something i'm missing because this is imported from a spring app that works. The code below is from the spring boot app

```
@Entity
@Table(name="project")
public class Project implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="teamId")
    private int teamId;

    //private String Rentabiliteit;

    @Column
    //@Index(name="IProject_status",columnNames="Status")
    private String status;

    @Column
    //@Index(name="IProject_naam",columnNames="Naam")
    private String naam;
    //public Prototype m_Prototype;
    //public Team m_Team;

}
```

SQL

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `project` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`teamId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`status` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`naam` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=43 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

ERROR

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:           
 Unknown column 'project0_.team_id' in 'field list'
```

Edited: Application.yml

```
spring:

mvc:
  view:
    prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
    suffix: .jsp

datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/oxyplast
    username: oxyplastuser
    password: oxyplastuserpw

jpa:
  properties:
    hibernate:
      current_session_context_class: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext 
      namingStrategy: org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy
```

Comment: I doubt if the problem is in the code you posted. Can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: https://github.com/thibitus/SE4-Oxyplast/tree/master/OxyplastSpringBoot

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu That's way too long but I this is causing the problem

Comment: Looked at the domain package. Project is the only class that is annotated as entity. Remaining are normal classes. Is it correct? Can you post partial stacktrace that has root cause string in it?

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu https://gyazo.com/f1189d7e7accbb5849cf0326e3ffcd6f

Comment: This github thread is useful: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2129

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**SINCE SPRING-BOOT 1.4**

Starting from 1.4, because of the switch to Hibernate 5, the naming strategy has been updated to `SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy` which [should be very close](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes#naming-strategy) to 1.3 defaults.

**See also:**

- [Spring's naming strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25293929/1199132)

---

**PREVIOUS VERSION**

Spring Boot provides the [`ImprovedNamingStrategy`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/ImprovedNamingStrategy.html) as default naming strategy, which makes Hibernate search for a `team_id` column (inferred from the `int teamId` field). As this column doesn't exist in your table, that's the cause of the error. From the Hibernate docs:

> An improved naming strategy that prefers embedded underscores to mixed case names

You've got two options:

1. **Provide the column name explicitly** as `@Column(name="teamId")`. There used to be a [bug](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2129) with this in early Boot versions, not anymore.
2. **Change the naming strategy** in the Spring Boot properties and tell it to use the [`EJB3NamingStrategy`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/EJB3NamingStrategy.html), which doesn't convert camelCase to snake_case, but keeps it as it is.

Comment: I provided the explicid column name, could it be mapped differently by hiberante? Is there a way to see this?

Comment: and in my application.yml there is this line

Comment: namingStrategy: org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy

Comment: Well i tried to change the name in the database and then it says that the entity is not mapped

Comment: I've solved the problem by renaming it teamid ( without capital I )! Thanks a lot for the partience and help

Comment: add these properties solved it for me: --spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl --spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

Comment: I solved the problem by adding this line in the file application.properties: 
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

Comment: How do you configure projections: i.e when mapping java interface to SQL views? I have a table with a lot of columns and renaming them in the view just seems like a bad way to do it. Currently it's allowing underscores but the interface will not pick it up. They have to match 100%

Comment: Hello, @TheRealChx101, it's been a while since I don't do Hibernate, but working with views should be exactly the same as with tables. However, be careful with views involving expensive queries, most engines such as MySql don't cache them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789332/is-a-mysql-view-faster-than-a-normal-query

Comment: @XtremeBiker I'm using PostgreSQL. The views work without issue but the interface's `getXXX` methods must exactly match the column names. i.e: a view with `id, first_name, last_name` will not match `getFirstName(), getLastName()`, but will match `getFirst_Name(), getLast_Name()`. On the other hand, an entity will match. So, as you can see, in order for the projection to match, I have to write the view with camel case naming, which means selecting the columns from the tables individually.

Answer (score 27):

If you are using Spring Boot 2.0.2 and Hibernate 5.3.4 then setting the following property will fix the issue.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

Comment: I tried the same in my project it is not working. I have posted my question in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61010482/oracle-jdbc-oracledatabaseexception-ora-00972-identifier-is-too-long

Answer (score 3):

Spring boot 3

```
spring:
  jpa:
    open-in-view: false
    show-sql: true
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    hibernate:
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy
        implicit-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy
```

- physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy
- implicit-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy

Answer (score 1):

Below strategy worked for me

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultComponentSafeNamingStrategy
```

Comment: spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy does not exists in latest version this solution might work but will not in the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

with the late version :

```
    spring-boot-starter-data-jpa: ➡ 1.5.2.RELEASE
    hibernate-core:5.0.12.Final
```

this class

```
PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

needs to be extended and added to hibernate properties.

Here is a full working version

```
    public class PhysicalNamingStrategyImpl extends PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl implements Serializable {

    public static final PhysicalNamingStrategyImpl INSTANCE = new PhysicalNamingStrategyImpl();

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalTableName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment context) {
        String nameModified;
        // Do whatever you want with the name modification
        return new Identifier(nameModified, name.isQuoted());
    }

}

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalColumnName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment context) {
         String nameModified;
        // Do whatever you want with the name modification
        return new Identifier(nameModified, name.isQuoted());
    }
```

Linking it to hibernate should be done like this when configuring the datasource.

```
properties.put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", "my.Package.PhysicalNamingStrategyImpl");
```

here is a full working version of datasource config

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
        basePackages = { "com.xxxxxx.repository" }
)
public class SharedDataSourceConfig {

    @Value("${startup.ddl-auto}")
    String hbm2ddl;

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.shared")
    public DataSource customerDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", hbm2ddl);
        properties.put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", "my.package.PhysicalNamingStrategyImpl");
        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages(PackageScannerHelper.getPackagesToScan())
                .persistenceUnit("shared")
                .properties(properties)
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory
                    entityManagerFactory
    ) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with spring boot 1.4.0 and hibernate entitymanager 4.3.8.Final

**application.properties**

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

Answer (score 0):

> application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultComponentSafeNamingStrategy
```

the above properties work for me.
hibernate 4.3.11.Final
spring boot 1.4.2.RELEASE