# Hibernate naming strategy causing "Unknown column" error in Java Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm working on a Spring Boot application using Hibernate and Lombok. I have an entity class Product mapped to a product table in my database. Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ProductId")
    private int id;
    // Other fields...
}
```

When I run my application, I get the following error:

`ERROR o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper : Unknown column 'p1_0.product_id' in 'field list'`

It seems like Hibernate is converting the camel-case field name 'ProductId' in my entity class to the underscore-separated column name 'product_id' in the database, causing a mismatch.

I tried changing the @Column annotation to match the actual column name in the database, but it didn't solve the issue. I also checked my database schema and it does have a 'ProductId' column.

Is there a way to change the Hibernate naming strategy so that it doesn't automatically convert the field names? I want the names in my entity class to directly map to the column names in the database without any modifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysql is case insensitive. If you use case sensitive column name then it will convert the camel case to the snake case.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate Naming Strategy: Hibernate by default converts the camel-case field names in the entity class to underscore-separated column names in the database ([java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column in 'field list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38948289/java-sql-sqlsyntaxerrorexception-unknown-column-in-field-list)). This means that 'ProductId' in the entity class would be mapped to 'product_id' in the database, which might be causing the issue. You can change Hibernate's naming strategy to avoid this automatic conversion.

`spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl` 
This should be added to your **application.properties** file to change the naming strategy ([What am I mapping incorrectly? Unknown column in the 'field list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63413656/what-am-i-mapping-incorrectly-unknown-column-in-the-field-list)).