# Hibernate renames some columns at start with Spring Boot 1.4

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm having some problems with my PostgreSQL database columns on some tables.

If I declare a column of `String` with a name like `a_column_name` *Hibernate* accepts the column of the table with the name `a_column_name`.

But my problem comes when I declare the column type to `Integer` or `BigDecimal`. At start, *Hibernate* creates a new column of type `int4` or `numeric(19, 2)` with a name like **acolumnname** with NULL's.

`Hibernate: alter table t_myTable add column acolumnname int4`

or

`Hibernate: alter table t_myTable add column acolumnname numeric(19, 2)`

I've tried to set the [name-strategy on the config file of Spring boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes#naming-strategy):

```
jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: false
      hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
      hibernate.generate_statistics: true
      naming.physical-strategy: PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

But with no result...

So my question is why Hibernate accepts the column name when it's of *String* type but doesn't like it when it's *Integer* or *BigDecimal*.

Regards.

---- Update 1 ----

After search the Entity to post here the code as *Veselin Davidov* asked, I've noticed that some columns are accepted while others not.

The entities are created from a company framework that parses a JSON with the DB structure (tables, fields, type of fields...) and generates the JAVA entity class. So after see the answer from SAM I've changed the code of the Entity template to add a `@Column(name = "your_column_name")`. Now, when Hibernate starts, it doesn't add the columns with the wrong names and uses the DB columns.

Comment: Can you show us your entity? Why not add the column name in the entity class?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36451620/hibernate-field-naming-issue-with-spring-boot-naming-strategy/36452366

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay, I was trying to find the problem and I did it. I've updated the description and how I solved the problem thanks to SAM answer. Thanks anyway for your time and help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your Hibernate entity class is like the following:

```
@Entity
public class Registration{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column
    @Basic
    private String name;

    // getters and setters

}
```

then your registration table will have fields named with "id" and "name" as you have used `auto-ddl=update`. To avoid that you can specify the column names with `@Column(name = "your_column_name")` like below:

```
@Table(name = "registration")
@Entity
public class Registration{

   @Id
   @Column(name = "r_id")
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private int id;

   @Basic
   @Column(name = "r_name")
   private String name;

   // getters and setters

}
```

If you are using `Intellij IDEA` then the IDE can generate the required Entity class.

You can go to your persistence tab -> right-click on your project name -> Generate Persistence Mapping -> By Database Schema. Then select the tables whose Entity you want to generate. Voila everything comes with ease.

Now coming to your problem, in your Entity class if you set some filed with `Integer` type then it will update your table to `int4` and with `allow null`. The `BigDecimal` is also same `numeric(10,2)` with `allow null`. To avoid `allow null` in your database use primitive type `int` and `double`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Your solution inspired me to see what the problem was. Thank you!

Comment: Happy Coding !!