# How to fix "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'product0_.return_policy' in 'field list' " exception?

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring-boot

I've been getting this "SQLSyntaxErrorException:Unknown column 'product0_.return_policy' in 'field list'" when I try to run the URL on my browser to *GET* all the *products*.

[Look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AM0pG.png)

**The browser shows the below as well:**

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
> could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

*returnPolicy* is the only variable that's causing this problem. I'm able to successfully retrieve all the values from the database when I remove the variable itself from both the database and from the Product class in Java.

**This is the *getAllProducts* method that is part of the RESTController:**

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/products")
    public List<Product> getAllProducts() {
        return productService.getAllProducts();
    }
```

which works fine when I remove the returnPolicy variable altogether.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZjnh.png) is the MySQL table description:

**Values stored in returnPolicy column:**

> returnPolicy

```
  0 
  0 
  1 
  1 
  1
```

**This is the code for the 'Product' model's variables:**

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="product")
public class Product {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int price;
    private String vendor;
    private String description;
    private Boolean returnPolicy;
```

### ProductRepository

```
@Repository public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, String>{ }
```

Is there a problem with the mapping between SQL tinyint(Boolean) and the Boolean type of Java?

Comment: I'm a newbie, so pardon me if this is a trivial issue

Comment: quite well-described question for a newbie.

Comment: Haha thanks. This is my first ever question :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hibernate is assuming that the entity field `returnPolicy` corresponds to the table column `return_policy`. But actually, the column name is `returnPolicy`

Hibernate follows a naming strategy as to what column name should it derive from entity field names. You should explicitly specify whether to use `ImplicitNamingStrategy` or `PhysicalNamingStrategy`. Hibernate provides out of the box classes for this.

Alternatively, for this specific issue, annotating the field with explicit column name will make is understand.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36451620/hibernate-field-naming-issue-with-spring-boot-naming-strategy) SO answer for more.

Comment: In concreto, with annotation: `@Column(name="returnPolicy") Boolean returnPolicy;` or simply `Boolean returnpolicy;` (ugly)

Comment: Thank you! Renaming the column as 'return_policy' did the trick for me.

Comment: Using the @Column(name="returnPolicy") made no difference though (not sure why). In fact, I'd tried that too before posting the question here

Answer (score 0):

Your `returnPolicy` is not mapped with column `return_policy` you can quick fix this with following

### Method1

```
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int price;
    private String vendor;
    private String description;
    @Column(name = "return_policy")
    private Boolean returnPolicy;
```

### Method2

`@JsonNaming` annotation is manage naming strategy as to what column name should it derive from entity field names.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyNamingStrategy;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonNaming;

@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int price;
    private String vendor;
    private String description;
    private Boolean returnPolicy;
```

Comment: I'd tried method-1 before posting the question. It didn't work for me

Comment: use second method, if still face same issue then post your repository code

Comment: The second method isn't making any difference either. Renaming the column in sql as return_policy worked though.

This is the repository class:
`@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, String>{
}`
This is the code in my service class:
`@Autowired
 private ProductRepository productRepository;
 
 public List<Product> getAllProducts() {
  return productRepository.findAll();
 }`

Comment: remove `@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)` from model and then start again

Answer (score 0):

You can use this annotation `@Transient`  if you don't use attribute as column in database

`@Transient` annotation in JPA or Hibernate is used to indicate that a field is not to be persisted or ignore fields to save in the database. `@Transient` exist in javax. persistence package. It is used to annotate a property or field of an entity class, mapped superclass, or embeddable class.

You can use it in this way .

```
@Transient
    private String token;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate converts the camel case lettering to underscores by default. so you either change your columns in your table to reflect that or change hibernate naming strategy.
Add the below in the application.properties file:

`spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl`