# Spring repository sends HQL to database server

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I have a simple spring data repository which extends CrudRepository

Also I configured

```
<context:component-scan base-package="by.acme.vt.*"/>
```

and

```
 <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="eqDataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
        <!-- Set JPA properties -->
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
                <prop key="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action">none</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <!-- Set base package of your entities -->
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <array>
                <value>by.acme.vt.asdint</value>
                <value>by.acme.vt.asd.domain</value>
                <value>by.acme.vt.asd.repository</value>
            </array>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

and

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="by.acme.vt.*" entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
```

So

```
by.acme.vt.asdint
```

belongs to the project which I am working on but packages

```
 <value>by.acme.vt.asd.domain</value>
 <value>by.acme.vt.asd.repository</value>
```

belongs to the included jar file
If I create the same repo in the project, it works fine but for repositories which were included in jar, even when I run a simple code like

```
myrepo.findById(id)
```

It sends a pure HQL to the server, so it does not transform it to SQL at all.

I see response from mssql like.

```
table MyUser does not exist on server.
```

But it supposed to use my_user table but not MyUser

Comment: Please post the statement that gets executed if you really think it is HQL (I doubt that). It's more likely that you have the wrong naming strategy.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36452366/66686