# hibernate not use @column(name='') annotation

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I use springboot 2.6 and postgres 15 and hibernate 5.7
I use database Generate persistence Mapping to make entity from database schema;
When I run application with this config:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
```

table properties name not work.
for example this is my field:

```
@Basic
@Column(name = "isEnabled", nullable = false)
private boolean isEnabled;
```

When I run applicataion get this error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing column [is_enabled] in table [analytics]
```

Comment: Spring sets its own naming convention on your columns, turning 'isEnabled' into "is_enabled". See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36451620/hibernate-field-naming-issue-with-spring-boot-naming-strategy

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hibernate field naming issue with Spring Boot (naming strategy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36451620/hibernate-field-naming-issue-with-spring-boot-naming-strategy)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add the following annotation to your `Analytics` entity definition?

```
@Table(name = "analytics", schema = "public")
```

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 problems. first is field name. seccond is table name;
first problem fix with this config in application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

this fix first problem. but seccond problem not fix.
you should change table name with this trick:
@Table(name = ""analytics"")

Answer (score 0):

You shoud mark annotation your **getter-method** instead of field. Try to use:

```
@Column(name = "isEnabled", nullable = false)
public boolean isEnabled() {
    // your getter 
}
```

Ensure you have this method and mark it by this annotation.